# ZFS dedup block usage?

Tags: zfs, deduplication

How can I list all the ZFS dedup blocks and the files that are associated with each one?

e.g.:

```
BLOCK    FILES
e6b678a  /pool/a/file1
         /pool/a/file2
```

If that's not possible, what about determining which deduplicated blocks are being used within a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current tools, this is not possible. If you are a developer, you could write one.